# Encoding issue in java after compilation

Tags: java, encoding, ant, build

My java code has lot of danish characters. These characters appear fine in eclipse and I have no issues in compilation using ISO encoding.

But the problem is after compilation it is appearing in strange forms like `Ã`¸ can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You "compile in ISO"? What's wrong with utf-8?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're compiling the code. You need to ensure that the compiler uses the encoding of the .java file.

If using `javac`, specify the `-encoding` argument.

If using Ant, specify the `encoding` attribute on the `<javac>` task.

In Eclipse, each source file can have a different encoding. You shouldn't use this if you also want to compile using `javac` or Ant.

---

Next, you problem might be displaying the text when running your code. If you're generating HTML, you need to ensure that the text is inserted into HTML in the encoding of the HTML, so the browser can display the text correctly. HTML encoding is normally specified on the `charset` parameter in a `Content-Type` header field, or a META declaration.

Comment: i added encoding in my ant task but still i am getting the same issue.But the strange thing is come classes are compiling correctly while some are not.i did it like this                                                                      <javac srcdir="${dir.src}" destdir="${dir.classes}" includes="**/*" debug="${debug}" classpath="${classpath}"  deprecation="on"  encoding="ISO-8859-1" />                                                                             I am using danish character.is there any other encoding tht i should use

Comment: @user2134322 A better option might be `UTF-8`, but `ISO-8859-1` should be fine. Since you're editing in Eclipse, you might have saved some of the file in a different encoding. Check the encoding Eclipse is using on the properties dialog of each file.